# Using ngFor to create unique IDs for elements

Tags: angular

If I have an accordion like this, how would I use the index to append to `data-target` and `id`
so that not all items expand and collapse at once?

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
<div class="accordion" id="accordion">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header" id="heading">
        <h2 class="mb-0">
          <div class="btn btn-link collapsed"
          data-toggle="collapse"
          data-target="#collapse"
          id = "card-head"
          aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse">
            {{item.name}} {{item.lastName}}
          </div>
        </h2>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading"
      data-parent="#accordion">
        <div class="card-body">
            <p>{{item.content}}</p>
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Edit</button>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Consider creating a new AccordionComponent which would have an "opened" state and you'll manage one by one. Moreover, since I see id's I suppose you are using a plain JS/jQuery for DOM manipulation which is not very good practise in terms of Angular, because it has a powerful mechanisms for that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add dynamic index from ngFor to html attribute value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42837214/how-to-add-dynamic-index-from-ngfor-to-html-attribute-value)